# How to get remaining usage limits from google translate api

Tags: google-api, translation

Is there a way (via an API call) to get the usage limits in the google translate API?

I can login to the developer console, but I want to have a script to poll the limit and warn me when I get above a certain threshold.

There are only three calls here: http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/translate/v2/
and nothing about getting the remaining allowance of a quota.